# Sort the list by the number values in alphanumeric elements

Tags: python

What is the best way to sort the below list only by the number part of the list elements to get the expected result?

```
l = ["V1", "P18", "V3", "A2", "V4"]
```

expected output:

```
["V1", "A2", "V3", "V4", "P18"]
```

expected output:

```
["V1", "A2", "V3", "V4", "P18"]
```

Comment: will it always end with a number like that?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
l = ["V1", "P18", "V3", "A2", "V4"]

l.sort(key=lambda k: int(k[1:]))
print(l)
```

Prints:

```
['V1', 'A2', 'V3', 'V4', 'P18']
```

---

EDIT: Alternative using `re` (if there are more characters at the beginning):

```py
import re

l = ["V1", "P18", "V3", "A2", "V4"]

l.sort(key=lambda k: int(re.search(r"\d+$", k).group(0)))
print(l)
```

Comment: A little fragile as it requires only one alphabetic character before the numbers.

Comment: @Chris I've posted an alternative with `re`

Comment: Suggestion: compile the regular expression before calling `sort`

Comment: @Chris Python `re` module implements caching of expressions: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d5ebf8b71fd18d7a1f2f6b670a2c18749dc2b55e/Lib/re/__init__.py#L335 So it's usually not necessary to compile regexes beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

More universal code

```
import re

def sort_by_numeric_part(element):
    match = re.search(r'\d+', element)
    if match:
        return int(match.group())
    else:
        return float('inf')

l = ["V1", "P18", "V3", "A2", "V4"]
l = sorted(l, key=sort_by_numeric_part)
```

Comment: this should probably raise an error instead of returning `float('inf')`